# Create bins on groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my data frame got a column `department` and `rank`

```
name  dept  Rank
"A"  "ENG"  1
"A"  "MGMT"  1
"B"  "ENG"  2
"C"  "MGMT"  2
"D"  "MGMT"  3
"E"  "ENG"  3
```

I want to create bins in each `dept`.

```
name  dept  Rank  Comment
"A"  "ENG"  1  Good
"A"  "MGMT"  1  Good
"B"  "ENG"  2  Avg
"C"  "MGMT"  2  Avg
"D"  "MGMT"  3  Poor
"E"  "ENG"  3  Poor
```

I'm able to do this by below code

```
 df['Comment'] = pd.qcut(df[df['dept'] == "ENG"]['Rank'], q=[0.0, .25, .5, 1.0], labels=['Good', 'Avg', 'Poor'])
 df['Comment'] = pd.qcut(df[df['dept'] == "MGMT"]['Rank'], q=[0.0, .25, .5, 1.0], labels=['Good', 'Avg', 'Poor'])
```

I'm very sure, there must be some way using `groupby`, but can't figure it out.

Comment: It's strange that you are able to use quantiles greater than 1. Are you sure your example is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform`/`groupby.apply`:

```
df['Comment'] = (df
 .groupby('dept')['Rank']
 .transform(lambda g:
     pd.qcut(g,
             q=[0, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3],   # changed
             labels=['Good', 'Avg', 'Poor']))
 )
```

*NB. quantiles are in the range [0, 1], I changed the example.*

Output:

```
  name  dept  Rank Comment
0    A   ENG     1    Good
1    A  MGMT     1    Good
2    B   ENG     2     Avg
3    C  MGMT     2     Avg
4    D  MGMT     3    Poor
5    E   ENG     3    Poor
```

Comment: thanks for highlighting, i have corrected the code in question, Also it would be great if you could explain your solution. Btw it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what to explain, it just does the same as you did but per group. Let me know if you have a specific question.

Comment: yeah, you are correct. just thought like adding details about `transform`, what does it do. i didn't think about the solution you gave, because i don't know about `transform`. Thanks for the efficient solution though.

Comment: how to handle the exception while doing the qcut

`ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([60., 60., 60., 60., 60.]).`

Comment: basically this error is coming because in any of the group, if there is only 1 row with Rank 60, then this error comes.

Comment: Transform is similar to apply but works on individual series and returns the same shape. In your case it shouldn't matter. The`ValueError` is a limitation of `qcut`, you can check the `duplicates`option. I can't test right now.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it be simpler to create a dictionary and map the values? Since you would need to do it anyways while creating the labels and mapping to the bins

```
d={1:'Good',
   2:'Avg',
   3:'Poor'}

df['comments']=df['Rank'].map(d)
df
```

```
    name    dept    Rank    comments
0   "A"     "ENG"     1     Good
1   "A"     "MGMT"    1     Good
2   "B"     "ENG"     2     Avg
3   "C"     "MGMT"    2     Avg
4   "D"     "MGMT"    3     Poor
5   "E"     "ENG"     3     Poor
```

Comment: I guess the example is not ideal. Quantiles are usefull for non-discrete data. For example if you have a rank of 2.5.

Comment: yes @mozway, i agree

Comment: just posted the sample data, rank goes to over 100, so mapping is not the solution i guess.

Comment: @Naveed quantiles are susceptible to the number of items, so you really need to do it per group if you want a mapping that is independent for each group (again the example here is oversimplified)